# Помогите составить регулярное выражение обрезающие символы после двоеточия до конца

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть три отдельные строчки:

```
    Получил от тебя: The weather is great today
    Получил от тебя: School
    Зашифрованный текст: LJL KSLLJLF WD YTLOH EGFHM
```

Хочу чтобы регулярка выбирала все слова после двоеточия (там всегда на английском). Самое гениальное что я придумал: `[A-Za-z]+`, но он выводит в список слова по одному, их можно потом объединить - но это не то. Наверняка есть решение элегантнее

Comment: Почему вам не нравится `text.split(':')[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместе с двоеточием:

```
:.*
```

Без двоеточия:

```
(?<=:).*
```

Без двоеточия если оно встречается в строке ровно один раз:

```
[^:]*$
```

Во всех случаях заменить на пустую строку.

Ещё можно сохранить двоеточие заменой по первой регулярке на `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял:

```
original = """Получил от тебя: The weather is great today
Получил от тебя: School
Зашифрованный текст: LJL KSLLJLF WD YTLOH EGFHM"""

texts = []

for i in original.split('\n'):
    temp = i.split(':')
    if len(temp) > 3:
        text = ':'.join(temp[1:-1])
    else: text = temp[1]

print(texts)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: а регулярные выражения здесь где, подскажите?